# How to put a margin in a page?

Tags: zwpagelayout

Today I am willing to know how to put a border in a page?

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.3in}  
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}     
\setlength{\textheight}{10.2in}   
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.3in}    
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-.3in}  
\setlength{\topskip}{.2in}     


\begin{document}
Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. \\
Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text 
text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text 
text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. 
Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text 
text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text 
text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. 
Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text 
text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text 

text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text 
text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text 
text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. 
Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text 
text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text 
text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. 
Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text 
text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text 


text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. 
Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text 
 text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text 
text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text 
text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text 
text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. 
Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text 


text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text 
text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. 
Text text text text. 


\end{document}
```

How to put a border around the page? Also this should be in all other pages too.
Kindly help me, Thank you in advance

Comment: @Harish Kumar Help me sir

Comment: Not  sure what you want: have a frame around each page?

Comment: I think so sir.

Comment: You should set your margins using package `geometry`, if you need a frame for debugging, use the package option `showframe`.

Comment: It depends whether you want a frame to debug the page geometry, or a frame as a decoration.

Comment: borders and frames have been addressed by peter wilson in his "glisterings" column in tugboat.  two columns worth looking at are in [volume 32:2, example of a fancy border](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-2/tb101glister.pdf), and [volume 32:1, framing of smaller areas](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100glister.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tikzpagenodes` package with `eso-pic` or `background` for this job. 
A sample with `eso-pic`:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}   %% for dummy text
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.8in, headsep=0in, heightrounded, nomarginpar]{geometry}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
  \AtPageUpperLeft{
     \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
       \draw [red!80,very thick]
            ([shift={(-5mm,-5mm)}]current page text area.south west)
            rectangle
            ([shift={(5mm,5mm)}]current page text area.north east);
     \end{tikzpicture}
  }
}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `background`:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}   %% for dummy text
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.8in, headsep=0in, heightrounded, nomarginpar]{geometry}

\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
opacity=1,
angle=0,
color=black,
contents={%
     \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
       \draw [red!80,very thick]
            ([shift={(-5mm,-5mm)}]current page text area.south west)
            rectangle
            ([shift={(5mm,5mm)}]current page text area.north east);
     \end{tikzpicture}
  }
}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

Both of these will take 2-3 compilations to settle down.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a frame around *the text* with the `framed` package. In this code, I reproduced your layout with the geometry package, which clearly shows a problem: the last line is at the bottom of the physical page.

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\setlength{\topskip}{.2in}

\usepackage[top=0.87in, left=0.7in, headsep=0in, height=10.2in, width=7in, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{framed}

\colorlet{framecolor}{LightSalmon1}
\setlength\FrameRule{2pt}
    \newenvironment{colourframed}{%
    \def\FrameCommand{\fboxrule=\FrameRule\fboxsep=\FrameSep \fcolorbox{framecolor}{white}}%
    \MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}}%
    {\endMakeFramed}

    \newenvironment{colourframed*}{%
    \def\FrameCommand{\fboxrule=\FrameRule\fboxsep=\FrameSep \fcolorbox{framecolor}{white}}%
    \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
    {\endMakeFramed}

\begin{document}

\begin{colourframed*}
Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. \\
Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text
text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text
text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text.
Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text
text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text
text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text.
Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text
text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text

text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text
text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text
text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text.
Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text
text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text
text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text.
Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text
text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text


text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text.
Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text
 text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text
text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text
text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text
text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text.
Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text


text text text. Text text text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text
text. Text text text text. Text text text text. Text text text. Text text text text.
Text text text text.

\lipsum[1-12]
\end{colourframed*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]